# Bootstrap hover layer over image

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a row of images with a layers on top of each of them with a description. The top layer should fit the image perfectly, however it's filling the full size of the block including the padding that it should be inside of instead.

The site is using bootstrap. The images need to be responsive, which I think is what's causing the issue.

I've tried adding additional divs with various settings to act as masks etc but nothing is working.

The code is below.. I've simplified it a little to show what's going wrong without the rest of the bloat.

```
    <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 projects-box">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12 text-center"><h2>Main Title</h2></div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-4 home-projects">
            <a class="home-project-content" href="#">
              <img class="home-project-image" alt="Project 1" src="http://placehold.it/365x365">
              <div class="home-project-info">
                <strong>Project Title 1</strong><br>
                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</div>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4 home-projects">
            <a class="home-project-content" href="#">
              <img class="home-project-image" alt="Project 2" src="http://placehold.it/365x365">
              <div class="home-project-info">
               <strong>Project Title 2</strong><br>
                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</div>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4 home-projects">
            <a class="home-project-content" href="#">
              <img class="home-project-image" alt="Project 3" src="http://placehold.it/365x365">
              <div class="home-project-info">
                <strong>Project Title 3</strong><br>
                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</div>
            </a>
        </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and the css

```
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.projects-box {
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}
.projects-box h2 {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
.projects-box .home-projects {
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
}

.projects-box .home-project-content {
  display: block;
}
.projects-box .home-project-image {
  display: block;
}

.projects-box .home-project-info {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7); 
  color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
  position: absolute; 
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

http://www.bootply.com/qj8SwPzl75

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `position: relative;` to `.projects-box .home-project-content`

http://www.bootply.com/9DHmuFvGvf

Comment: So simple.. I've been staring it trying all sorts for well over an hour... Thanks...

Comment: I was looking similar effect but also centering text vertically. I made a modification of your code, if someone needs it: https://www.bootply.com/oezryper4G